# ReferenceError: require is not defined (on my rest api)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, rest

**doesn't work**
Hey guys i have tried so many ways to fix this problem but i can´t really find a answer fot this.

I am making an rest API for my web site in react, and i am very new to this...
i am trying to connect my server.js file to my routes.js file but it doesn´t let me beacuse it doesn´t recognise de "require".

```
    import express from "express";
import cors from 'cors';
import mysql from 'mysql';
const routes = require('./routes');

app.use(cors());
const app = express();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'marioquiz'
});


app.use(express.json());
app.use(routes);
app.use('/User',routes);


app.get('/',(req,res)=>  res.send('O servidor esta a funcionar...'));

app.listen(5000);
```

And returns me this Error:

```
file:///C:/Users/Mario/Desktop/Master/Backend/src/server.js:4

const routes = require('./routes');
           ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///C:/Users/Mario/Desktop/Master/Backend/src/server.js:4:16
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:146:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:165:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

Comment: You cannot use `require()` from an ESM module file.  Use `import` instead.  In case you didn't realize, a module in nodejs is either CommonJS or ESM.  CommonJS is the original type of module file and uses `require()` to load other modules.  The newer type of JS module is ESM and only uses `import` to load other modules.  You can only be one type of file so can only use one type of syntax for importing modules in any given module.  This module is currently specified as an ESM module so can only use import to load other modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `require` keyword is used for [CommonJS modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), but it looks like you've configured Node.js to run your application using [ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html). The equivalent way to bring in `routes` using ECMAScript modules is something like:

```
import { routes } from './routes.js';
```

Bear in mind that you will have to write your `routes.js` file to be ECMAScript modules compatible also, something like:

```
const routes = [
  ...
];

export { routes };
```